# Convert Zope data to Mysql

Tags: mysql, zope

How to Convert Zope 2.1 data to Mysql db. Have any way to convert? I want argent please.

Answer (score 4):

You will most likely have to write the conversion script manually.  Loop through the Zope objects you're interested in and create table rows for them.  Zope's Python Scripts and SQL Methods may come in handy.